# method-invoking Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I've declared the following bean in my Spring config

```
<bean id="templateCacheClearingTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="delay" value="5000" />
    <property name="period" value="5000" />

    <property name="timerTask">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject" ref="templateMailService" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="clearCache" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This should cause the `clearCache()` method of the `templateMailService` bean to be invoked every 5000ms, but nothing appears to be happening. Am I missing something?

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need:

```
<bean id="timerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
  <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
    <list>
      <ref bean="templateCacheClearingTask"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

In addition to what you already have.